# Migrating from H-code to AppMeasurement in adobe analytics

Tags: adobe-analytics

As per the adobe document https://marketing.adobe.com/resources/help/en_US/sc/implement/appmeasure_mjs_migrate.html I have updated each and every piece of code in appmeasurement.js but the code is not working. It doesn't give any error.

Initially i have added these 2 lines.
var s=s_gi(s_account);
s=new AppMeasurement();
Then all the code that i had in s_code.js. I have replaced new appmeasurent.js integrate module and the media module. I have downloded the code from here https://sc.omniture.com/p/am/1.3/index.html?a=CodeManager.Index&ssSession=6ecfe7a8f3ee22161af6a37226f160f6&jpj=43153526643383

After all this the analytics is not working. It is not firing any value. It is not giving any error also.How should i debug this? Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have a look at this blog post:
http://webanalyticsfordevelopers.com/2013/12/10/migrating-from-h-code-to-appmeasurement/

It really helped me to do this migration.

Comment: As per the reference 
1. Took the AppMeasurement code from admin and added it in the current s_code from the below line 

============== DO NOT ALTER ANYTHING BELOW THIS LINE ! ===============
2. Added this s=new AppMeasurement();
3. Changed  s.getQueryParam to s.Util.getQueryParam
4. Added updated integrate module which is compatible with AppMeasurement

But the code is not working and it is not even giving any error.

Any idea what may be the issue?

Comment: Did you make the change from s.getQueryParam to s.Util.getQueryParam correctly? This post shows how to do it in details (see step 4): [http://blogs.adobe.com/digitalmarketing/mobile/lighten-up-with-the-smaller-faster-analytics-javascript-for-web-mobile/](http://blogs.adobe.com/digitalmarketing/mobile/lighten-up-with-the-smaller-faster-analytics-javascript-for-web-mobile/)

Comment: nice reference. thankyou so much.  I had missed s.t() call in the end. It is working absolutely fine. I would need one last help. Do you know where do we have to get the new plugin code from? I need new T&T plugin.